# How can I extend a wx.grid.GridCellRenderer?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

This is my code. I want to override the Draw method

```
import  wx.grid             as  gridlib

class MyCellRenderer(gridlib.GridCellRenderer):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        gridlib.GridCellRenderer.__init__(self, *args)  

    def Draw(self, *args):
        super(MyCellRenderer,self).Draw(*args)
```

... in other part of the script

```
        r2 = MyCellRenderer()
        # self is a grid here
        self.SetCellRenderer(15,0, r2)
```

This is the stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\SY_FI\wxPython-2.8.12.1\demo\GridSimple2.py", line 274, in <module>
    frame = TestFrame(None, sys.stdout)
  File "c:\SY_FI\wxPython-2.8.12.1\demo\GridSimple2.py", line 264, in __init__
    self.grid = SimpleGrid(self, log)
  File "c:\SY_FI\wxPython-2.8.12.1\demo\GridSimple2.py", line 96, in __init__
    r2 = MyCellRenderer()
  File "c:\SY_FI\wxPython-2.8.12.1\demo\GridSimple2.py", line 13, in __init__
    gridlib.GridCellRenderer.__init__(self)
  File "D:\ATHENA~1\RELEAS~1\build\ext\vc90_xp/lib\python2.6\site-packages\wx-2.8.12.0\wx\grid.py", line 113, in __init__

AttributeError: No constructor defined
```

The version of wx is 2.8.12.0. python is 2.6.6. platform is winxp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should extend MyCellRenderer from PyGridCellRenderer